# How to get all groups that a user is a member of?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, active-directory, powershell-2.0

PowerShell's [`Get-ADGroupMember`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617193.aspx) cmdlet returns members of a specific group. Is there a cmdlet or property to get all the groups that a particular user is a member of?

Answer (score 374, accepted):

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` from the [Active Directory module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/) will do this. You'll need that module, or RSAT on Windows 10+, installed to run the command below.

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name

name
----
Domain Users
Domain Computers
Workstation Admins
Company Users
Company Developers
AutomatedProcessingTeam
```

Comment: I have tried this but found that it only returns the 'Domain Users' group for any user.

Comment: The above was giving me errors ("The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error" - presumably functionality not available on the server).  `get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof` worked fine though.

Comment: Perfect. Could use the username environment variable to show the current user:  `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $env:USERNAME | select name`

Comment: Note that the Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership requires a "global catalog server" - without that it returns the error "Directory Object Not Found" even though the object is confirmed to exist via Get-ADUser cmdlet and it has membership. Response from @schmeckendeugler worked very well for me to get group membership.

Comment: I had a particular username I was trying to run this for, `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership DatabaseRemoverDevAppPool` but it kept failing with `Cannot find an object with identity: 'DatabaseRemoverDevAppPool'`. I ran it as `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership DatabaseRemoverDevAp` and it succeeded. The difference is that `DatabaseRemoverDevAppPool` is the cn but the sAMAccountName  was `DatabaseRemoverDevAp`. Apparently `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` looks up by sAMAccountName, not cn.

Comment: Unfortunately, [the `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet is broken in such a way that makes it fundamentally unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057379/), so I don't recommend using it. The script I posted in linked answer works correctly, though.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart It's only broken if you use characters that need to be escaped in AD usernames or group names which is an uncommon situation because that's not a recommended practice by Microsoft in the first place. It's certainly a useful caveat to be aware of, but it's also a _far cry_ from "fundamentally unreliable".

Comment: I will agree to (rather strongly) disagree. In many AD environments, for example, the "/" character is _required_ in AD object names. I stand by my "fundamentally unreliable" assessment as the built-in cmdlets should handle characters that are perfectly valid (albeit need escaping) in AD.

Answer (score 147):

Single line, no modules necessary, uses current logged user:

```
(New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$($env:username)))")).FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().memberOf
```

Kudos to this vbs/powershell article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730963.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this no-modules version. I simply changed the variable from `$env:username` to `$username` and set with `$username = "testuser"` to easily do variable substitution for other user lookups.

Comment: Does not work correctly for nested membership of user's DEFAULT GROUP. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451706/ldap-matching-rule-in-chain-not-working-with-default-ad-groups-domain-users

Comment: To get (sorted) plain list of groups only, you can run `(New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$($env:username)))")).FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry().memberOf -replace "CN=(.*?),.*" ,"``$1" | Sort`.

Answer (score 63):

A more concise alternative to the one posted by Canoas, to get group membership for the currently-logged-on user.

I came across this method in this blog post: http://www.travisrunyard.com/2013/03/26/auto-create-outlook-mapi-user-profiles/

```
([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)").Findone().Properties.memberof
```

An even better version which uses a regex to strip the LDAP guff and leaves the group names only:

```
([ADSISEARCHER]"samaccountname=$($env:USERNAME)").Findone().Properties.memberof -replace '^CN=([^,]+).+$','$1'
```

More details about using the [ADSISEARCHER] type accelerator can be found on the scripting guy blog: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/24/use-the-powershell-adsisearcher-type-accelerator-to-search-active-directory.aspx

Comment: Both of these give me the error : Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The samaccountname= search filter is invalid."

Comment: Strange.... I just tested it again, but on Windows 7 in a completely different environment, and it works fine here too.

Comment: I tried again just now, still on Win 7, and it does work fine.  Perhaps I had typo when first trying this out.  Thanks for adding the replace to strip out the forest "guff".

Comment: Works great, append `| Sort-Object` to make it even more readable.

Comment: Does not work correctly for nested membership of user's DEFAULT GROUP. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451706/ldap-matching-rule-in-chain-not-working-with-default-ad-groups-domain-users

Answer (score 45):

Old school way from CMD:

```
net user mst999 /domain
```

Comment: it also works on client machines without extra AD tools

Comment: Unfortunately - if your groups names are long (ie > 21 characters) then it will truncate them...

Answer (score 31):

```
(GET-ADUSER –Identity USERNAME –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
```

Comment: | get-adgroup 
will output the group objects. Brilliant!

Comment: or, use $env:USERNAME instead to grab the username of the currently logged in user

Comment: Does not work with default group. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451706/ldap-matching-rule-in-chain-not-working-with-default-ad-groups-domain-users

Comment: THIS is the right one folks. All these other answers either don't work at all, require other tools, truncate the output or are too complex.

Comment: Essentially results in the same:
Get-AdUser _username_ -Properties MemberOf | select -Expand MemberOf

Answer (score 23):

This should provide you the details for current user. Powershell not needed.

`whoami /groups`

Comment: This is helpful only for the logged in user AD group membership. However if you need another user or are running from an elevated shell this is not helpful.

Comment: This is not what was asked though:, "How to get all groups that a user is a member of?"

Answer (score 13):

If you cannot get Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership to work for you could try logging in as that user then use.

```
$id = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
$groups = $id.Groups | foreach-object {$_.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])}
$groups | select *
```

Comment: You don't need to login as the user either if you use something like `$id = [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]("username")`

Comment: This shortens nicely to the one-liner `[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups | % {$_.Translate([Security.Principal.NTAccount])}`.

Comment: THAT is a TERRIBLE answer, as that violates every company's security to NOT do that.

Comment: @PatrickBurwell I get your point. I was thinking more of cases where you cannot access something but one of your collegues can, or your helping somone via teamviewer or something... rather than someone doing it to lots of users without a users knowledge

Answer (score 9):

While there are many excellent answers here, there is one which I was personally looking for that was missing.  Once I figured it out - I thought I should post it in case I want to find it later, or it actually manages to help someone else at some point:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | Format-Table -auto
```

A second approach for presenting this is to specify the individual columns you are interested in eg:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name, GroupScope, GroupCategory
```

This gives all the AD groups the username belongs to - but also presents all of the default properties of each group formatted nicely as a table.

The key benefit this gives you is you can see at a glance which are distribution lists, & which are Security groups.  You can further see at a glance which are Universal, which are DomainLocal & which are Global.
Why would you care about this last bit?

- Universal group is a security or distribution group that contains
  users, groups, and computers from any domain in its forest as
  members. You can give universal security groups rights and
  permissions on resources in any domain in the forest.
- Global group is a group that can be used in its own domain, in member
  servers and in workstations of the domain, and in trusting domains.
  In all those locations, you can give a global group rights and
  permissions and the global group can become a member of local groups.
  However, a global group can contain user accounts that are only from
  its own domain.
- Domain local group is a security or distribution group that can
  contain universal groups, global groups, other domain local groups
  from its own domain, and accounts from any domain in the forest. You
  can give domain local security groups rights and permissions on
  resources that reside only in the same domain where the domain local
  group is located.

Comment: I agree. This is the better solution if you want to DO something with the output in PowerShell (which a sysadmin probably will). Also a lot easier to remember than the -I admit- very elegant oneliner-solution that was proposed and upvoted for 100+ times.

Comment: Excellent, nice table output, "This gives all the AD groups the username belongs to - but also presents all of the default properties of each group formatted nicely as a table."

Answer (score 5):

Get group membership for a user:

```
$strUserName = "Primoz"
$strUser = get-qaduser -SamAccountName $strUserName
$strUser.memberof
```

See *[Get Group Membership for a User](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-windows-powershell/417715-get-group-membership-user.html#post1668928)*

But also see Quest's [Free PowerShell Commands for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).

[**Edit**: **Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership** command is included in Powershell since v2 with Windows 2008 R2.  See kstrauss' answer below.]

Comment: Actually there's an easier way with Quest cmdlets: Get-QADGroup -Contains Primoz

Comment: This is no longer the best answer as Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership is now built into PowerShell

Comment: Voted down because It would be much better to use Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership.  I would like to undo this downvote, but I cannot.  I will edit the answer to point out that the built in option now exists.

Comment: Now you make it easy to use: 
#Get-PromptedUser-AllGroupMemberships.ps1
$user = Read-host -prompt "Waht us do you need all group memberships for?"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Format-Table -auto

Answer (score 5):

Get-Member is not for getting user's group membership. If you want to get a list of groups a user belongs to on the local system, you can do so by:

```
$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Account.Name='DemoUser1',Domain='DomainName'} WHERE ResultRole=GroupComponent ResultClass=Win32_Account"

Get-WMIObject -Query $query | Select Name
```

In the above query, replace DemoUser1 with the username you want and the DomainName with either your local computer name or domain name.

Comment: This query is very time consuming and responds very slow when there are multiple users and groups in the environment

Comment: Whoever is editing the answer make sure you edit it the right way. I was suggesting the OP to replace DemoUser1 with whatever username he wants. And, you completely changed that meaning.

Comment: This may be slow, but it gets the right response:

Answer (score 4):

`Get-Member` is a cmdlet for listing the members of a .NET `object`.  This has nothing to do with user/group membership.  You can get the current user's group membership like so:

```
PS> [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups | 
         Format-Table -auto

BinaryLength AccountDomainSid    Value
------------ ----------------    -----
          28 S-1-5-21-...        S-1-5-21-2229937839-1383249143-3977914998-513
          12                     S-1-1-0
          28 S-1-5-21-...        S-1-5-21-2229937839-1383249143-3977914998-1010
          28 S-1-5-21-...        S-1-5-21-2229937839-1383249143-3977914998-1003
          16                     S-1-5-32-545
...
```

If you need access to arbitrary users' group info then @tiagoinu suggestion of using the Quest AD cmdlets is a better way to go.

Answer (score 4):

First, import the ActiveDirectory module:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

Then issue this command:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group | foreach-object {
    Write-Host $_.SamAccountName
}
```

This will display the members of the specified group.

Comment: The OP asks for the opposite. Get all groups a specified user is member of.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a PowerShell function called Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive. It accepts the DSN of a user, computer, group, or service account. It retrieves an initial list of groups from the account's memberOf attribute, then recursively checks those group's memberships. Abbreviated code is below.  Full [source code with comments can be found here](http://www.reich-consulting.net/2013/12/05/retrieving-recursive-group-memberships-powershell/).

```
function Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive( ) {

    Param(
        [string] $dsn,
        [array]$groups = @()
    )

    $obj = Get-ADObject $dsn -Properties memberOf

    foreach( $groupDsn in $obj.memberOf ) {

        $tmpGrp = Get-ADObject $groupDsn -Properties memberOf

        if( ($groups | where { $_.DistinguishedName -eq $groupDsn }).Count -eq 0 ) {
            $groups +=  $tmpGrp           
            $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive $groupDsn $groups
        }
    }

    return $groups
}

# Simple Example of how to use the function
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a username"
$groups   = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive (Get-ADUser $username).DistinguishedName
$groups | Sort-Object -Property name | Format-Table
```

Comment: Does not work correctly with user's DEFAULT GROUP. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451706/ldap-matching-rule-in-chain-not-working-with-default-ad-groups-domain-users

Comment: Does this function get all nested grouping as well?

Answer (score 4):

No need for long scripts when it is a simple one liner..

**QUEST Command**

```
(Get-QADUser -Identity john -IncludedProperties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
```

**MS AD Command**

```
(GET-ADUSER –Identity john –Properties MemberOf | Select-Object MemberOf).MemberOf
```

I find the MS AD cmd is faster but some people like the Quest ones better..

Steve

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name | export-CSV username.csv
```

This pipes output of the command into a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file.

Answer (score 4):

For LOCAL users and groups (ie not in Active Directory), and if you don't want to, or aren't allowed to, or can't install RSAT and/or `Install-WindowsFeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell` and/or `import-module activedirectory` then here's a pure, pre-installed powershell (5.1+) way to do it.

(Note: `Get-LocalGroup*` used below are only available Powershell v5.1 and above. "...v5.1 was released along with the Windows 10 Anniversary Update on August 2, 2016, and in Windows Server 2016. ...[F]or Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2012, and Windows Server 2012 R2 [it] was released on January 19, 2017." ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell)))

```
$username = "user002"
Get-LocalGroup | ForEach-Object {
    # the usernames are returned in the string form "computername\username"
    if (Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $_ | Where-Object name -like "*\$username") {
        $_.name
    } 
}
```

Example output:

```
Administrators
Users
```

Comment: This method is unrelated to Active Directory.

Comment: @Slogmeister Extraordinaire My reasoning is that some Internet users searching for this question will be interested in local groups not in active directory

Comment: @johnvkrumpf Understood, but your answer does not indicate that it is not an Active Directory solution.  It suggests that if you can't load the AD module/tools that this will work, but it will not in this context.  The question specifically requests an AD solution.  I'm not against your reasoning, however as I have done the same plenty of times.  However, consider that the reader may not understand that your answer doesn't work with AD and be very frustrated trying.  Modify your answer to clearly indicate this is a non-AD solution and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

It is just one line:

```
(get-aduser joe.bloggs -properties *).memberof
```

end of :)

Comment: Piping that to a `select -expandproperty memberof` will make the output a little more readable/useful.

Answer (score 2):

The below works well:

```
get-aduser $username -Properties memberof | select -expand memberof
```

If you have a list of users:

```
$list = 'administrator','testuser1','testuser2'
$list | `
    %{  
        $user = $_; 
        get-aduser $user -Properties memberof | `
        select -expand memberof | `
        %{new-object PSObject -property @{User=$user;Group=$_;}} `
    }
```

Comment: #Get-PromptedUser-AllGroupMemberships.ps1
$user = Read-host -prompt "What us do you need all group memberships for?"
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Format-Table -auto

Answer (score 2):

```
(Get-ADUser $env:username -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf | % {$_.split(",")[0].replace("CN=","")}

Domain Users
Domain Computers
Workstation Admins
Company Users
Company Developers
AutomatedProcessingTeam
```

Comment: Hi, this question already has an answer, if you have a different solution, that is better in some way, try to explain how it or when it is better than the approved one

Answer (score 1):

Get-QADUser -SamAccountName LoginID | % {$_.MemberOf } | Get-QADGroup | select name

Answer (score 1):

```
   Get-ADUser -Filter { memberOf -RecursiveMatch "CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com" } -SearchBase "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com"  -SearchScope Base
                  ## NOTE: The above command will return the user object (Administrator in this case) if it finds a match recursively in memberOf attribute.
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the following to work for a particular user:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username
```

It threw an error that I was not willing to troubleshoot.

I did however come up with a different solution using Get-ADUser.  I like it a bit better because if you don't know the account name then you can get it based off of a wildcard on the user's actual name.  Just fill in **PartOfUsersName** and away it goes.

```
#Get the groups that list of users are the member of using a wildcard search

[string]$UserNameLike = "*PartOfUsersName*" #Use * for wildcards here
[array]$AccountNames = $(Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $UserNameLike}).SamAccountName

ForEach ($AccountName In $AccountNames) {
Write-Host "`nGETTING GROUPS FOR" $AccountName.ToUpper() ":"
(Get-ADUser -Identity $AccountName -Properties MemberOf|select MemberOf).MemberOf|
    Get-ADGroup|select Name|sort name
    }
```

Huge props to schmeckendeugler and 8DH for getting me to this solution.  +1 to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

To get it recursive, you can use:

```
<# 
    .SYNOPSIS   
        Get all the groups that a user is MemberOf.

    .DESCRIPTION
        This script retrieves all the groups that a user is MemberOf in a recursive way.

    .PARAMETER SamAccountName
        The name of the user you want to check #>

Param (
    [String]$SamAccountName = 'test',
    $DomainUsersGroup = 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=net'
)


Function Get-ADMemberOf {
    Param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [PSObject[]]$Group,
        [String]$DomainUsersGroup = 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=grouphc,DC=net'
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($G in $Group) {
            $G | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name
            Get-ADGroup $G -Properties MemberOf| Select-Object Memberof | ForEach-Object {
                Get-ADMemberOf $_.Memberof
            }
        }
    }
}


$Groups = Get-ADUser $SamAccountName -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
$Groups += $DomainUsersGroup
$Groups | Get-ADMemberOf | Select -Unique | Sort-Object
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do not have privileges to consult other member groups but you do have the privilege to consult group members, you can do the following to build a map of which user has access to which groups.

```
$groups = get-adgroup -Filter * | sort name | select Name
$users = @{}
foreach($group in $groups) {
    $groupUsers = @()
    $groupUsers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.Name | Select-Object SamAccountName
    $groupUsers | % {
        if(!$users.ContainsKey($_.SamAccountName)){
            $users[$_.SamAccountName] = @()
        }
        ($users[$_.SamAccountName]) += ($group.Name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Studying all comments presented gave me a starting point (thanks for such) but left me with several unresolved issues.  As result here is my answer.  The code snippet provided does a little more than what is asked for but it provides helpful debugging info.

```
[array] $script:groupsdns = @()
function Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive() 
{
  Param( [string] $dn, [int] $level = 0, [array] $groups = @() )

  #if(($groupsdns | where { $_.DistinguishedName -eq $dn }).Count -ne 0 ) { return $groups } # dependency on next statement
  #$groupsdns += (Get-ADObject $dn -Properties MemberOf) # Get-ADObject cannot find an object with identity
  if ($script:groupsdns.Contains($dn)) { return $groups }
  $script:groupsdns += $dn
  $mo = $Null
  $mo = Get-ADObject $dn -Properties MemberOf # Get-ADObject cannot find an object with identity
  $group = ($dn + " (" + $level.ToString())
  if ($mo -eq $Null) { $group += "!" }
  $group += ")"
  $groups += $group
  foreach( $groupdn in $mo.MemberOf )
  {
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -dn $groupdn -level ($level+1) -groups $groups
  }
  if ($level -le 0) 
  { 
    $primarygroupdn = (Get-ADUser -Identity $dn -Properties PrimaryGroup).PrimaryGroup 
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -dn $primarygroupdn -level ($level+1) -groups $groups
  }
  return $groups
}
$adusergroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive -dn $aduser.DistinguishedName
$adusergroups | ft -AutoSize | `
              Out-File -Width 512 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecursive.txt #-Append #-Wrap # | Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to clarify.  Do this first:
$aduserDistinguishedName = "CN=name,OU=..."
$aduser = Get-ADUser -Identity $aduserDistinguishedName -Properties *

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter * | foreach-object {
write-host "User:" $_.Name -foreground green
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | foreach-object {
        write-host "Member Of:" $_.name
    }
}
```

Change the value of -SearchBase to reflect the OU you need to list the users from :)

This will list all of the users in that OU and show you which groups they are a member of.

Answer (score 0):

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership USERLOGON | select name

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to just get the names:

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership "YourUserName"`

`# Returns
distinguishedName : CN=users,OU=test,DC=SomeWhere
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
name              : testGroup
objectClass       : group
objectGUID        : 2130ed49-24c4-4a17-88e6-dd4477d15a4c
SamAccountName    : testGroup
SID               : S-1-5-21-2114067515-1964795913-1973001494-71628`

Add a select statement to trim the response or to get every user in an OU every group they are a user of:

`foreach ($user in (get-aduser -SearchScope Subtree -SearchBase $oupath -filter * -Properties samaccountName, MemberOf | select samaccountName)){
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountName | select name}`

Answer (score 0):

Almost all above solutions used the `ActiveDirecotry` module which might not be available by default in most cases.

I used below method. A bit indirect, but served my purpose.

List all available groups

`Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Group`

And then list the groups the user belongs to

`[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Groups`

Comparison can then be done via checking through the `SIDs`. This works for the logged in user. Please correct me if I am wrong. Completely new to PowerShell, but had to get this done for a work commitment.

Comment: If you are checking a user which is already a member of the Administrator group, make sure start PowerShell by "Run As Administrator", otherwise the groups won't be listed out correctly for the 2nd command...took quite a while to figure this out...windows...

Answer (score 0):

With user input and fancy output formatting:

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)] 
Param( 
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)] 
    [String]$UserName 
) 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
If ($UserName) { 
    $UserName = $UserName.ToUpper().Trim() 
    $Res = (Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | Measure-Object).Count 
    If ($Res -GT 0) { 
        Write-Output "`n" 
        Write-Output "$UserName AD Group Membership:" 
        Write-Output "===========================================================" 
        Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | Select-Object -Property Name, GroupScope, GroupCategory | Sort-Object -Property Name | FT -A 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here for future reference. I'm in the midst of an email migration. I need to know each user account and its respective group membership, and also I need to know each group and its respective members.

I'm using the code block below to output a CSV for each user's group membership.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * |`
  ForEach-Object { `
    $FileName = $_.SamAccountName + ".csv" ; `
    $FileName ; `
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_ | `
      Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, name, GroupScope, GroupCategory | `
        Sort-Object -Property SamAccountName | `
          Export-Csv -Path $FileName -Encoding ASCII ; `
  }
```

The export process for the groups and their respective members was a little convoluted, but the below works. The output filenames include the type of group. Therefore, the email distribution groups I need are/should be the Universal and Global Distribution groups. I should be able to just delete or move the resulting TXT files I don't need.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * | `
 Select-Object -Property Name, DistinguishedName, GroupScope, GroupCategory | `
  Sort-Object -Property GroupScope, GroupCategory, Name | `
   Export-Csv -Path ADGroupsNew.csv -Encoding ASCII

$MyCSV = Import-Csv -Path .\ADGroupsNew.csv -Encoding ASCII

$MyCSV | `
 ForEach-Object { `
  $FN = $_.GroupScope + ", " + $_.GroupCategory + ", " + $_.Name + ".txt" ; `
  $FN ; `
  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.DistinguishedName | `
   Out-File -FilePath $FN -Encoding ASCII ; $FN=""; `
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple oneliner to recursively search all the groups a user is member of:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | foreach-object { Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | select SamAccountName }
```

To filter the groups to find out if user is member of a specific group i use this:

```
if ( Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserName | foreach-object { Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_.SamAccountName | select SamAccountName } | where-object {$_.SamAccountName -like "*$Groupname*"} ) { write-host "Found" } else { write-host "not a member of group $Groupname" }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for PowerShell, you could use the command line tool [`gpresult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/gpresult) as follows:

```
gpresult /USER domain\username /R
```

You may omit the `/USER` portion to display the information for the currently logged on user:

```
gpresult /R
```

Example output:

> ```
> Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Operating System Group Policy Result tool v2.0
> © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Created on ‎10/‎01/‎2024 at 10:14:48
>
>
> RSOP data for DOMAIN\username on SYSTEM : Logging Mode
> -------------------------------------------------------
>
> OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
> OS Version:                  10.0.19045
> Site Name:                   N/A
> Roaming Profile:             N/A
> Local Profile:               C:\Users\username
> Connected over a slow link?: No
>
>
> USER SETTINGS
> --------------
>     CN=full name,OU=organisation unit,DC=some
>     Last time Group Policy was applied: 10/01/2024 at 09:00:00
>     Group Policy was applied from:      server
>     Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
>     Domain Name:                        MEDEL
>     Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later
>
>     Applied Group Policy Objects
>     -----------------------------
>         usrPolWindowsAccounts
>         (list of applied group policies)
>
>     The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
>     -------------------------------------------------------------------
>         usrPolGermanGermany
>             Filtering:  Denied (Security)
>         (list of denied group policies)
>
>     The user is a part of the following security groups
>     ---------------------------------------------------
>         Domain Users
>         Everyone
>         Remote Desktop Users
>         BUILTIN\Users
>         NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
>         CONSOLE LOGON
>         NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
>         This Organization
>         LOCAL
>         secUsersEnglish
>         (list of security groups)
> ```

In contrast to the [`net user` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/net-commands-on-operating-systems) (as suggested in [user4511672](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4511672)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28237181)), the group names are not truncated.