# Service running as network service/local system: failed to add entries to ActiveDirectoryContainer (DirectoryOperationException:No Permissions)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, active-directory

I have two Windows services (one runs as network service and the other runs as local system). And the system in which these services are running are part of domain. These services uses active directory as central store and the idea is to be able to add/remove/read entries from this store.

We are simply using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.BeginSendRequest(DirectoryRequest request .... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection.beginsendrequest(v=vs.110).aspx ) and passing AddReuest as input to add entries to the Active Directory.

However, the operation is failing with System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.**DirectoryOperationException** with message The user has **insufficient access rights** (same error for both network service as well as computer/local system account). But I did add the computer account to the store in Active Directory and granted full permissions on the store. I am not sure what I am missing?

Is it not possible to **add/remove entries** on active directory even though computer account has granted full permissions? (I thought local system/network service simply pass the computer credentials over network - I have taken quick peek at the following links for reference [The difference between the 'Local System' account and the 'Network Service' account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510170/the-difference-between-the-local-system-account-and-the-network-service-acco) or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb680595.aspx)

Incidentally, please note that as long as I run the service with one of **the domain user accounts** the operations are passing. And **search** (read operations) are passing for all the accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You might be mistaking an authentication problem with an authorization problem. Granted, when nothing works, its hard to tell them apart.

The rights you set in AD are probably ok, but you never get there. In the security event log of the computer that hosts the Active Directory, there is probably a access denied for a network logon of `\\server_a`. On the Active Directory server, give the computer account (SERVER_A) the privilege "Access this computer from the network".

It will solve the authentication part, letting the process acquire an access token that will be used by Active Directory to perform authorization.

If you are in a low volume lab, you can also try to enable [Active Directory Diagnostic Logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961809.aspx), with the `Security Events` registry entry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to put this as an answer instead of a comment though I'm not yet sure if it will help.

When approaching permissions issues like this, I tend to think in terms of sets. I'd start by looking at the set of membership provided to your two different test cases, the machine account and service account with something like a powershell script described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20410668/44656.

It's possible that your service account has a permission granted via indirect membership that your machine account does not.

If that doesn't shed light on it, you can try enabling auditing on the ActiveDirectory server and looking for the failed access attempts. Usually a failed permission check does a decent job of highlighting why something is being denied. Auditing can be configured via global auditing policy and setting SACLs on specific object(s) you are interested in.