# Powershell script for writing in an excelsheet

Tags: excel, powershell

Writing a powershell script here to fill some data from our AD to an excelsheet. I am struggling with one issue though..

I use this line to read out the stuff I want in the variable $accounts:

```
$accounts = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=technicalaccounts,OU=ztechnical,DC=XXX,DC=XXX,DC=XX" -Properties memberof, passwordlastset, description, enabled
```

Then the filling up the excelsheet follows in a Foreach

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,1).FormulaLocal = $value.name
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,2).FormulaLocal = $value.description
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,3).FormulaLocal = $value.passwordlastset
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,4).FormulaLocal = $value.enabled
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,5).FormulaLocal = $value.memberof
```

The problem occurs when it's doing this one

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,5).FormulaLocal = $value.memberof
```

The error says this:

> Ausnahme beim Festlegen von "FormulaLocal": "Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"
>   In \Get-TechUser.ps1:57 Zeichen:9
>   +                                 $Sheet.Cells.Item($row,5).FormulaLocal = $value.memberof
>   +                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseAdapterSetValueTI

Is this an array in an array kinda thing?

Well anyway thanks for any advice :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all groups that a user is a member of?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072996/how-to-get-all-groups-that-a-user-is-a-member-of).

Comment: Nah different issue.. but thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memberof property is a collection (ADPropertyValueCollection) of the Group Memberships. 
You can i.e. use the join Operator:

```
$Sheet.Cells.Item($row,5).FormulaLocal = $value.memberof -join ";"
```