# How to get all groups that a mail-contact belongs to?

Tags: powershell, office365

This code will find all groups to which a particular email account or `mail-user` account belongs.

```
get-group | where-object -FilterScript {$_.Members -contains $user}
```

However, in O365 you can have `mail-contacts` who are not users - they are used just for mailing lists; they don't have a `windowsliveid`, so they won't be found in `$_.Members`.

How can I find all groups that a particular `mail-contact` belongs to?

Comment: Please check this link:[How to get all groups that a user is a member of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072996/how-to-get-all-groups-that-a-user-is-a-member-of)

Comment: I'm working with Office365 online; I don't think I can use Active Directory powershell.  Or at least, when I do, it connects me to my local AD.

Comment: Also, the examples in that thread require a username.  Mail-Contacts do not have a username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [likeafoxx over in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/9x1tyo/powershell_to_create_account_then_add_to_group/) came up with a solution.

```
$contact = Get-Contact -Identity "<Contact's Name>"
Get-Group | Where-Object {$_.Members -contains $contact}
```

Apparently, if you catch the `get-contact` value into a variable, then `get-group`'s `$_.members` can search for *that*.  I was putting the string value for the name there, but that always turned up empty.  This works like a charm.