# LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN not working with default AD groups - Domain Users

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory, ldap

In my program, I need to fetch all the AD groups for a user.
The current version of my program uses System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups.

This works good until we had a new customer with a much largeer AD. There it is really slow. (Up to 60 seconds)

Now I've been looking around, and saw the posts that the AccountManagement is easy to use, but slow.

I also found that LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN should also fetch all the nested groups that a user is member of. And is more performant.

From [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/f238d2b0-a1d7-48e8-8a60-542e7ccfa2e8/recursive-retrieval-of-all-ad-group-memberships-of-a-user?forum=ITCG) link.

But I'm having an issue with the default groups that in AD exists.

For example the group "Domain Users" is not returned by the function.
They also have a group "BDOC" that as member have "Domain Users". That group is also not returned.

Trough the GetAuthorizationGroups it is returned correct.

I'm using following code to fetch the groups by user.

**VB.NET:**

```
Dim strFilter As String = String.Format("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})", oUserPrincipal.DistinguishedName)
Dim objSearcher As New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher("LDAP://" & oLDAPAuthenticationDetail.Domain & If(Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(oLDAPAuthenticationDetail.Container), oLDAPAuthenticationDetail.Container, String.Empty))
objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
objSearcher.Filter = strFilter
objSearcher.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(sPropGuid)
objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add(sPropDisplayName)


Dim colResults As DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection = objSearcher.FindAll()
```

Afterwards I was testing with the script from the link, if it was possible to fetch all the users from the Domain Users group, by changing the "member" to "memberOf" in the filter.
When I put the Domain Admins group in the filter, it shows the admins correct.
When I put the Domain Users group in the filter, it returns nothing.

**Powershell:**

```
$userdn = 'CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=acbenelux,DC=local'
$strFilter = "(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$userdn)"
$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://rootDSE")
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$($objDomain.rootDomainNamingContext)"
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Base"
$colProplist = "name"
foreach ($i in $colPropList)
{
    $objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i) > $nul
}
$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
{
    $objItem = $objResult.Properties
    $objItem.name
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Or is it maybe just not possible to fetch the "default groups" with that filter?
What is a good alternative then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default group is odd. It is not stored in `memberOf`, or even in the `member` attribute of the group. That's why your search won't find it. The default group is determined by the `primaryGroupId` of the user. That attribute stores the RID (the last part of the SID) of the group. It's kind of dumb, I know :)

I actually wrote an article about the 3 (yes 3) different ways someone can be a member of a group: [What makes a member a member?](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/07/what-makes-a-member.html)

I also wrote an article about getting all of the groups a single user belongs to, and how to account for all 3 ways: [Finding all of a user’s groups](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/06/08/finding-all-of-a-users-groups.html)

For example, here is the C# code I put in that article about how to find the name of the primary group for a user (given a `DirectoryEntry`). It shouldn't be too hard to translate that to VB.NET:

```
private static string GetUserPrimaryGroup(DirectoryEntry de) {
    de.RefreshCache(new[] {"primaryGroupID", "objectSid"});

    //Get the user's SID as a string
    var sid = new SecurityIdentifier((byte[])de.Properties["objectSid"].Value, 0).ToString();

    //Replace the RID portion of the user's SID with the primaryGroupId
    //so we're left with the group's SID
    sid = sid.Remove(sid.LastIndexOf("-", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
    sid = sid + de.Properties["primaryGroupId"].Value;

    //Find the group by its SID
    var group = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://<SID={sid}>");
    group.RefreshCache(new [] {"cn"});

    return group.Properties["cn"].Value as string;
}
```

You are right that the `AccountManagement` namespace makes things easy, but it really does have terrible performance sometimes. I never use it anymore. I find that `DirectoryEntry`/`DirectorySearcher` gives you much more control of how often your code makes calls out to AD.

I have been meaning to write an article about writing high performance code with `DirectoryEntry`, but I haven't gotten around to it yet.

*Update:* So if you need the nested groups for the user, including membership through the primary group, then you can find the primary group first, then do an LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN search for groups that have both the user and the primary group as members:

```
 (|(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={userDN})(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={primaryGroupDN}))
```

*Update:* If you want to include `Authenticated Users` in your search (edit the `DC` portion of the `distinguishedName`):

```
 (|(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=S-1-5-11,CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=com)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={userDN})(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={primaryGroupDN})
```

Note that you can also use the `tokenGroups` attribute of a user to find out all of the authentication groups for a user. The `tokenGroups` attribute is a constructed attribute, so you only get it if you specifically ask for it (with [`DirectoryEntry.RefreshCache()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.refreshcache) or, in a search, add it to [`DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload).

The caveat is that `tokenGroups` is a list of SIDs, not `distinguishedName`, but you can bind directly to an object using the SID with the `LDAP://<SID={sid}>` syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the great post. I've tested the functions, and in my company we only have 1 domain. So I can't test the trusted domains part.
But I still have an issue with "A nested group who has the primary group as member".

From the example I can find what the primary group is for a user.
But take following example: user sgielen has as primairy group Domain Users.
Domain Users is member of Group A, and Group A is member of Group B.
How to get Domain Users+Group A+Group B?

Comment: There is no way to do that in one search. But after you find the primary group, you can use that in your search. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. In my company AD (30,32 sec -> 1,02 sec)
But I have 1 wierd thing in my company's AD. From the GetAuthorizationGroups I get that my User is in the following groups. But my user is not in them.
CN=Administrators,CN=Builtin,DC=acbenelux,DC=local
CN=Users,CN=Builtin,DC=acbenelux,DC=local
Any idea how that would happen?

Comment: The `Users` group likely has `Authenticated Users` in it, which is one of the ["well-known SIDs"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems) that have special meaning. I can't say why the `Adminstrators` group is showing up, but check it in AD and see what its members are. It's possible there is a similar thing going on there.

Comment: I made an update to my answer with some more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the Authenticated Users, that seems to be correct.
But the Administrators group, only have the user "Administrator" and the group "Domain Admins". And I'm not in the group "Domain Admins". (But I have been in the past, for a test. But I'm removed again from it.)

Comment: Is there any other groups or well-known SIDs in the Domain Admins? There must be a reason.

Comment: In the Domain Admins, there are 5 users. One of them is "Administrator", the others are users. https://ibb.co/HF5N926 https://ibb.co/R0pmMJ0

Comment: That is odd. I couldn't tell you then. It doesn't normally lie to you :)