# Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership An unspecified error has occurred

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am getting errors with Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership command on Windows 10 (x64) machine. I have installed the required RSAT- 'Active directory Domain service and Lightweight Directory service tools' and 'Server manager' dependencies as specified int [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-non-language-fod#remote-server-administration-tools-rsat) document.  I am able to execute Get-AdUser and see the results but    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership is throwing below error.

```
PS C:\Users\JYOTHI> Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership jyothi
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership gapalani
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (jyothi:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
```

I can try the other way

```
(Get-Aduser jyothi -Properties MemberOf | Select MemberOf).MemberOf
```

but like to know what is the fix for Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership

Comment: I've seen this with `Get-ADGroupMember` for members that are on an external, trusted domain. But not with `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`. When you export the contents of `memberOf`, do you noticed anything different about any of the groups?

Comment: did not see any special characters or any differences in the group, noticed the same command executing fine from the windows server machine

Comment: Do any of the groups contain the `/` character?

Comment: There is one group name contains '\'

Comment: Does the cmdlet fail if you query a user's group membership who is not a member of groups whose names contain the ```\``` or `/` character?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Forward slashes (`/`) are a [problem in .NET too](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29090), although I thought backslashes worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

As you have noticed, `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` fails with an obscure error if the reference object's name contains certain characters, or if it's a member of one or more groups that contain certain characters in their names.

I don't have definitive proof, but my testing indicates that the underlying issue is that `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`, internally, uses ADSI and fails to correctly escape distinguished names that contain [characters that need to be escaped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/ldap-adspath). (If this is the case, Microsoft should be using the [IADsPathname interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iads/nn-iads-iadspathname) to escape names correctly. This would be an embarrassing oversight on their part.)

Unfortunately, this problem renders the cmdlet broken and unusable in production environments.

Here's a relatively short PowerShell script that doesn't suffer from this annoyance and also supports retrieving recursive group memberships:

```
# Get-ADGroupMembership.ps1
# Written by Bill Stewart

#requires -version 2

# Version history:
# 1.0 (2019-12-02)
# * Initial version. Only searches the current domain.

<#
.SYNOPSIS
Gets the distinguished names of the Active Directory groups that have a specified object as a member.

.DESCRIPTION
Gets the distinguished names of the Active Directory groups that have a specified object, represented by the -Identity parameter, as a member.

.PARAMETER Identity
Specifies an Active Directory object. You can specify either the distinguishedName or the sAMAccountName of the object.

.PARAMETER Recursive
Specifies to include the object's nested group memberships.

.NOTES
If you use the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module and want Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup objects as output, pipe this command's output to the Get-ADGroup cmdlet.

.EXAMPLE
Get the distinguished names of the groups that the kendyer account is a member of:
PS C:\> Get-ADGroupMembership kendyer

.EXAMPLE
Get the distinguished names of the groups that the kendyer account is a member of, including nested groups:
PS C:\> Get-ADGroupMembership kendyer -Recursive

.EXAMPLE
Get the ADGroup objects representing the groups that the kendyer account is a member of (requires the Active Directory module):
PS C:\> Get-ADGroupMembership kendyer | Get-ADGroup
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
  [String[]] $Identity,

  [Switch] $Recursive
)

begin {
  $CommandName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

  # Set up Pathname COM object
  $ADS_ESCAPEDMODE_ON = 2
  $ADS_SETTYPE_DN = 4
  $ADS_FORMAT_X500_DN = 7
  $Pathname = New-Object -ComObject "Pathname"
  if ( -not $Pathname ) {
    return
  }
  [Void] $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("EscapedMode","SetProperty",$null,$Pathname,$ADS_ESCAPEDMODE_ON)

  # Outputs correctly escaped distinguished name using Pathname object
  function Get-EscapedName {
    param(
      [String] $distinguishedName
    )
    [Void] $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("Set","InvokeMethod",$null,$Pathname,@($distinguishedName,$ADS_SETTYPE_DN))
    $Pathname.GetType().InvokeMember("Retrieve","InvokeMethod",$null,$Pathname,$ADS_FORMAT_X500_DN)
  }

  # Outputs the memberOf attribute of an object using paged search (in case
  # an object is a member of a large number of groups)
  function Get-MemberOfAttribute {
    param(
      [String] $distinguishedName,
      [Ref] $memberOf,
      [Switch] $recursive
    )
    $searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(objectClass=*)"
    $searcher.SearchRoot = [ADSI] "LDAP://$(Get-EscapedName $distinguishedName)"
    $lastQuery = $false
    $rangeStep = 1500
    $rangeLow = 0
    $rangeHigh = $rangeLow + ($rangeStep - 1)
    do {
      if ( -not $lastQuery ) {
        $property = "memberOf;range={0}-{1}" -f $rangeLow,$rangeHigh
      }
      else {
        $property = "memberOf;range={0}-*" -f $rangeLow
      }
      $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Clear()
      [Void] $searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($property)
      $searchResults = $searcher.FindOne()
      if ( $searchResults.Properties.Contains($property) ) {
        foreach ( $searchResult in $searchResults.Properties[$property] ) {
          if ( $memberOf.Value.Count -gt 100 ) {
            Write-Progress `
              -Activity $CommandName `
              -Status "Getting membership of '$distinguishedName'" `
              -CurrentOperation $searchResult
          }
          if ( $recursive ) {
            if ( -not $memberOf.Value.Contains($searchResult) ) {
              Get-MemberOfAttribute $searchResult $memberOf -recursive
            }
          }
          if ( -not $memberOf.Value.Contains($searchResult) ) {
            $memberOf.Value.Add($searchResult)
          }
        }
        $done = $lastQuery
      }
      else {
        if ( -not $lastQuery ) {
          $lastQuery = $true
        }
        else {
          $done = $true
        }
      }
      if ( -not $lastQuery ) {
        $rangeLow = $rangeHigh + 1
        $rangeHigh = $rangeLow + ($rangeStep - 1)
      }
    }
    until ( $done )
    Write-Progress `
      -Activity $CommandName `
      -Status "Getting membership of '$distinguishedName'" `
      -Completed:$true
  }

  function Get-ADGroupMembership {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
      [String] $identity,
      [Switch] $recursive
    )
    $ldapString = $identity -replace '\\','\5c' -replace '\(','\28' -replace '\)','\29' -replace '\*','\2a' -replace '\/','\2f'
    $searcher = [ADSISearcher] "(|(distinguishedName=$ldapString)(sAMAccountName=$ldapString))"
    try {
      $searchResults = $searcher.FindAll()
      if ( $searchResults.Count -gt 0 ) {
        foreach ( $searchResult in $searchResults ) {
          $memberOf = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String]
          Get-MemberOfAttribute $searchResult.Properties["distinguishedname"][0] ([Ref] $memberOf) -recursive:$recursive
          $memberOf
        }
      }
      else {
        Write-Error "Cannot find an object with identity '$identity'." -Category ObjectNotFound
      }
    }
    catch {
      Write-Error -ErrorRecord $_
    }
    finally {
      $searchResults.Dispose()
    }
  }
}

process {
  foreach ( $IdentityItem in $Identity ) {
    Get-ADGroupMembership $IdentityItem -recursive:$Recursive
  }
}
```

I've also added this script as a [public gist on github](https://gist.github.com/Bill-Stewart/ac1e981088f8dbf0f1358ab511e94173) in case something needs fixing or if I add new features.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, however, for future reference, the below worked for me.

For most Errors like this:
$Error:
ActiveDirectoryServer:8250, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
Get-ADPrincipalgroupmembership -Identity 'Username' -ResourceContextServer 'Server name'
```

Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
Get-ADPrincipalgroupmembership -Identity 'Username' -ResourceContextServer 'Server name'

Answer (score -1):

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity "jyothi"`

Comment: Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity jyothi

Forget the quotes