# Grabbing Specific AD Groups that a User is a Member Of

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

Just can't for the life of me figure this out. What I am trying to do is get a list of all the groups that a user is a member of. Then I would like to pass those along and grab the specific groups that I am looking for.

Below is what I have so far:

```
(Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf ).MemberOf | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains 'Part of Group Name'}
```

This returns nothing. I have a feeling that I am not referencing the right property in my Where-Object but I am having a hard time finding what that is. I know the results of `(Get-ADUser $user -Properties MemberOf ).MemberOf` are:

```
CN=App - dyn_readuser_prod_WeblogicApps_NS,OU=Groups,OU=USCC,DC=int,DC=usc,DC=local
CN=App - dyn_readuser_prod_osb_NS,OU=Groups,OU=USCC,DC=int,DC=usc,DC=local
CN=App - dyn_readuser_prod_openshift_NS,OU=Groups,OU=USCC,DC=int,DC=usc,DC=local
CN=App - dyn_readuser_nonprod_WeblogicApps_NS,OU=Groups,OU=USCC,DC=int,DC=usc,DC=local
CN=App - dyn_readuser_nonprod_osb_NS,OU=Groups,OU=USCC,DC=int,DC=usc,DC=local
CN=App - dyn_readuser_nonprod_openshift_NS,OU=Groups,OU=USCC,DC=int,DC=usc,DC=local
```

I just can't figure out how to reference "CN".

Comment: A common mistake. The `-contains` **operator** is for checking if an string can be found in an array of strings. The string's own `.Contains` **method** is for checking if a substring can be found inside another string (and works case-sensitively). In this case I would advise using the `-like` operator (`$_.Name -like '*PartOfGroupName*'`) or use the regex `-match` operator (`$_.Name -match 'PartOfGroupName'`)

Comment: @Theo When i use `-like` it still ends up returning nothing. I'm thinking there might be an issue with `$_.Name`

Comment: @Theo - just for extra emphasis, i would change your `.Contains` to `.Contains()`. to me, that makes "this is a method" more clear.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey true, but unfortunately, it is too late to edit the comment..

Comment: The thing here is that you are explicitely expanding only the `.MemberOf` property, effectively removing all other properties like .Name. (you have a string array, nothing more) So in the `Where-Object` clause, you need to use just `$_ -like ..`.

Comment: @Theo - arg! i forgot that ... [*blush*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
(Get-ADUser $user -Properties memberOf).memberOf |
  Where-Object { $_ -like 'CN=*Part of Group Name*,*' }
```

The `(...).memberOf` syntax in PowerShell v3 and later is functionally equivalent to piping to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberOf`, so you could also write it this way:

```
Get-ADUser $user -Properties memberOf |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberOf |
  Where-Object { $_ -like 'CN=*part of group name*,*' }
```

(The second variation would be required in PowerShell v2 which doesn't support the `(...).memberOf` "syntactic sugar.")

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for thank you. I read your reply to the answer down below. His works as well, but i understand what youre saying about the object names not including characters that break the cmdlet. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's a cmdlet that works well for grabbing the group membership of a user. Try the following:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Select-String -Pattern 'Part of Group Name'
```

Comment: This is a good idea in principle, but unfortunately the [`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` cmdlet is broken in such a way that makes it fundamentally unreliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057379/) so I don't recommend using it. The script I posted in linked answer works correctly, though.

Comment: If you'd rather have the DN format over the plain/readable one, then expand the property of 'DistinguishedName'

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Interesting, I've used this cmdlet rather extensively and have never ran into an issue. Obviously if the OP has that issue, then the other method is favorable.

Comment: You are fortunate in that your object names don't include any of the characters that break the cmdlet (this becomes less and less likely in more heterogeneous AD environments). I strongly recommend not to use `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` in any production scripts.