# Need to export all users in active directory with specific memberof details

Tags: powershell

I need to export all users in active directory with specific memberof details. For example i need to export all the users details from active directory with specific memberof details like group starts like RDS. Rest of the groups i dont want to export in csv file.

```
get-aduser -filter * -Properties name,memberof |select name, @{n=’MemberOf’; e= { ( $_.memberof | % { (Get-ADObject $_).Name }) -join “,” }} | export-csv D:\users.csv -nti
```

Current Output

[image]

Comment: Just look up how to use the `-Filter` instead of using `*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grabbing Specific AD Groups that a User is a Member Of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67727108/grabbing-specific-ad-groups-that-a-user-is-a-member-of)

Comment: Should be straightforward using -filter and wildcards except you need to use the distinguished name of the group which memberof contains.

Comment: @js2010 At where i need to change. Kindly guide me. It would helpful for me

Comment: Something like this, but I can't see the full name, or if the full group name is right:  `get-aduser -filter "memberof -eq 'CHN-MFA-VPN,CHN_RDP,CHN-Corona-BCP,'"`

Comment: are all users member of at least one of the targeted groups? if some are not, do they need to be in the CSV file with an empty MemberOf column? may the primary group of some users be one of the targeted groups (the primary group is not listed in the MemberOf list)? are you in a mono-domain or multi-domains forest?

Comment: do you have nested groups and if so, how should they be listed? eg. if a user is member of RDS-1 and RDS-1 is included into RDS-2, should RDS-2 be listed in the CSV file in the memberOf colum for that user (memberOf does not list nested groups membership)?

Comment: Thanks for all now i am able to pull the what i am expected data