# Unspecified Error - Exporting all of one user's groups to a CSV

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to powershell.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Trying to export all of one user's AD groups to a CSV.  I know it's a bit hard coded but just trying to do something simple.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$UserName = “pball“ 

$ReportPath = “C:\Input\EricsStuff\userADgroups.csv“

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Username | select name, groupcategory, groupscope | export-CSV C:\Input\EricsStuff\userADgroups.csv


# Export to :
# C:\Input\EricsStuff\userADgroups.csv
```

Specifically the Error is :

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Input\EricsStuff\ExportUserGroups.ps1:7 char:1
+ Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $Username | select name, groupcategory ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (pball:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMemb 
   ership
```

Comment: This cmdlet is quite prone to errors (personal experience). See the answer from Bill_Stewart https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057379/get-adprincipalgroupmembership-an-unspecified-error-has-occurred

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know what sections of the code are actually writing to the console?  I want to try and get it to write to a txt or csv file instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you might have seen, there are many posts over the internet mentioning recurring issues with `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership`.

If you want to see a user's membership, the easiest way is to look at the user's `MemberOf` Active Directory attribute but since you're looking to get:

- `Name`
- `GroupScope`
- `GroupCategory`

This would require to query each group using `Get-ADGroup`. There are 2 alternatives I can think of, the first one is using `LDADFilter` to search for groups where the user's `DistinguishedName` is a member (in other words, where the user's `DN` is part of the group's `Member` attribute):

```
$UserName = "pball"
$ReportPath = "C:\Input\EricsStuff\userADgroups.csv"

$userDN = (Get-ADUser $UserName).DistinguishedName
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(member=$userDN)" |
Select-Object Name, GroupCategory, GroupScope |
Export-CSV $ReportPath
```

The problem with this approach is that you **will** only get the groups where user is a member of on the **current Domain**. If the user is member of groups that exist on a different Domain, this code will not display them.

Another alternative if you need to query all groups (on the current Domain and on other Domains) that the user is member of is to loop over the `MemberOf` property. This code has been tested and it works for me but can't tell for sure if it's going to work for you (most likely the `regex` to get the Domain's `DistinguishedName` can be improved but I'm bad with that).

```
$UserName = "pball"
$ReportPath = "C:\Input\EricsStuff\userADgroups.csv"

$membership = (Get-ADUser $UserName -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf
$membership | Group-Object { ($_ -split '(?=DC=)',2)[1] } | ForEach-Object {

    [adsi]$ldap = 'LDAP://{0}' -f $_.Name
    [string]$domain = $ldap.Name

    foreach($group in $_.Group)
    {
        Get-ADGroup $group -Server $domain
    }

} |
Select-Object Name, GroupCategory, GroupScope |
Export-CSV $ReportPath
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you

Comment: @ericwebster happy to help