# Output to CSV required when bulk AD users added to AD groups

Tags: powershell, automation, export-to-csv

I have a script which will add multiple AD users to multiple AD groups.

```
# Import the data from CSV file and assign it to variable
$List = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\BulkAddGroups.csv"

foreach ($User in $List) {
    # Retrieve UserSamAccountName and ADGroup
    $UserSam = $User.SamAccountName
    $Groups = $User.Group

    # Retrieve SamAccountName and ADGroup
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UserSam'" | Select-Object SamAccountName
    $ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select-Object DistinguishedName, SamAccountName

    # User does not exist in AD
    if ($ADUser -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "$UserSam does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
        Continue
    }
    # User does not have a group specified in CSV file
    if ($Groups -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "$UserSam has no group specified in CSV file" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Continue
    }
    # Retrieve AD user group membership
    $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam | Select-Object DistinguishedName, SamAccountName

    foreach ($Group in $Groups.Split(';')) {
        # Group does not exist in AD
        if ($ADGroups.SamAccountName -notcontains $Group) {
            Write-Host "$Group group does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
            Continue
        }
        # User already member of group
        if ($ExistingGroups.SamAccountName -eq $Group) {
            Write-Host "$UserSam already exists in group $Group" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
        } 
        else {
            # Add user to group
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $UserSam
            Write-Host "Added $UserSam to $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

The below is the format of the CSV file I use:

[image: CSV Format]

I require assistance in outputting the actions (whether it is successful or not in adding users to AD groups) into single CSV file.

**UPDATE 1**

@Theo ran your code and got these errors:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User1:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User1 to Group1
 group does not exist in AD
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User2:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User2 to Group1
 group does not exist in AD
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User3:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User3 to Group1
 group does not exist in AD
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User4:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User4 to Group1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User4:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User4 to Group2
 group does not exist in AD
```

My CSV file format was like this (I used semi colon as delimiter as you suggested):

[image: New CSV Format]

My output file was like this:

[image: Output file]

I don't know if I put the ; in the CSVs that has caused the issue.

BUT weirdly the users were added to the AD groups.

**UPDATE 2**

Theo I added the code you gave me.

MY CSV format:

[image: New CSV Format]

Ran the code again got the same error messages:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User1:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User1 to Group1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User2:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User2 to Group1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User3:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User3 to Group1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User4:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User4 to Group1
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : An unspecified error has occurred
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\BulkAddADGroups.ps1:56 char:31
+             $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (User4:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:0,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalGroupMembership
 
Added User4 to Group2
```

But this time you output file was semi correct:

[image: 2nd Results]

For some reason the output file didn't pick up the name of the 'Group 2' for 'User 4' but it gets even more weirder the user was actually added to the groups.

What it be worth just having a single group name in column 'Group' rather than having multiple groups in column 'Group'?

Like this instead:

[image: New CSV format]

**UPDATE 3**

It is soo close!!!

I runs perfect in PS that out put is:

```
Added User1 to Group1
Added User2 to Group1
Added User3 to Group1
Added User4 to Group1
Added User4 to Group2
```

It makes the changes in AD also!

But it the CSV output is shows as this:

[image: Latest CSV output]

Seems like it is not outputting Group2 for User 4, I happy to keep it this and just use the output of the PS prompt but if you could just get this tweaked I would appreciate it.

Comment: The error messages indicate you suffer from the bug with `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057379/get-adprincipalgroupmembership-an-unspecified-error-has-occurred). The problem seems te be that some of your usernames or group names in your environment have DistinguishedNames with characters in them that need to be escaped and Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership doesn't seem to do that..

Comment: As alternative to `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMemberShip`, you could try replacing the `$ExistingGroups =...` line in the code with `$ExistingGroups = $ADUser.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object Name`. For that to work, you must also do `$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UserSam'" -Properties MemberOf`.  (just append **-Properties MemberOf** there. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Theo Please see my update 3 above code run perfect! But issue with output to CSV if it can't be resolved happy to accept answer but the output I would love! Honestly just happy some is able to assist me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your input csv, it seems logical to first group the imported data by SamAccountName and then create new objects where all groups for each user are combined in the 'Group' column with a semi-colon as delimiter.
That way, you will also have the chance to eliminate any duplicates in the list.

```
# Import the data from CSV file, group on column SamAccountName and 
# output new objects where each item is a single user and all groups for that user
# are separated by a semi-colon in column 'Group'
$List = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\BulkAddGroups.csv" | Group-Object SamAccountName | 
        Select-Object @{Name = 'SamAccountName'; Expression = {$_.Name}},
                      @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = {$_.Group.Group.Split(";").Trim() | 
                                                      Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'} | 
                                                      Sort-Object -Unique}}
# get a list of all AD groups
$ADGroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter *

# capture the (object) output from the loop
$result = foreach ($User in $List) {
    # store the users SamAccountName in a variable for convenience
    $UserSam = $User.SamAccountName

    # User does not have a group specified in CSV file
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($Groups)) {
        Write-Host "$UserSam has no group specified in CSV file" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        # output an error object
        [PsCustomObject]@{Name = $UserSam; Group = $null; Result = 'Error: User has no group specified in CSV file'}
        Continue  # skip this user an proceed with the next
    }

    # Test if the user exists
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$UserSam'" -Properties MemberOf

    # User does not exist in AD
    if (!$ADUser) {
        Write-Host "$UserSam does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
        # output an error object
        [PsCustomObject]@{Name = $UserSam; Group = $null; Result = 'Error: User does not exist in AD'}
        Continue  # skip this user an proceed with the next
    }

    foreach ($Group in @($User.Group)) {
        # create an object to output
        $out = [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name   = $UserSam
            Group  = $Group
            Result = $null    # we'll fill this in later
        }            
        
        # Group does not exist in AD
        if (@($ADGroups).Name -notcontains $Group) {
            Write-Host "$Group group does not exist in AD" -ForegroundColor Red
            # fill the Result property and output the error object
            $out.Result = 'Error: Group does not exist in AD'
        }
        else {
            # Retrieve AD user group membership
            $ExistingGroups = $ADUser.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | Select-Object Name
            # Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership is buggy, see
            # https://stackoverflow.com/q/59057379/9898643
            # $ExistingGroups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $UserSam

            # User is already member of group
            if (@($ExistingGroups).Name -contains $Group) {
                Write-Host "$UserSam already exists in group $Group" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
                # fill the Result property and output the object
                $out.Result = 'Skipped: User is already member'
            } 
            else {
                # Add user to group
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $UserSam
                Write-Host "Added $UserSam to $Group" -ForeGroundColor Green
                # fill the Result property and output the object
                $out.Result = 'Success: User added to group'
            }
        }
        # output the object
        $out
    }
}

# now you can save the results in a csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Somewhere\Results.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Output of `$result` on screen:

```
Name  Group  Result                      
----  -----  ------                      
User1 Group1 Success: User added to group
User2 Group1 Success: User added to group
User3 Group1 Success: User added to group
User4 Group1 Success: User added to group
User4 Group2 Success: User added to group
```

Comment: could you see my last update (sorry for the delay on this had quite a lot going on)

Comment: @S.Mahmood Please try again. It seems you have added a semi-colon after every group in the csv, which means you will get an empty string there instead of a group name. I have now changed the code to take that into account by using `$Groups  = $User.Group.Split(";").Trim() | Where-Object {$_ -match '\S'}`. This way, empty or whitespace-only names are omitted.

Comment: ran your code please see update 2 on the question - near enough working.

Comment: @S.Mahmood Aha, that was a 'gotcha'... The declaration of the object to output in `$out` was in the wrong place. I also changed the way `$List` is created to save having to split/trim etc. the groups later on